# Check for numeric value with optional commas javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to check a value if it is numeric and optionally contains commas.

I tried

```
var input=3433;
var pattern=/^[1-9]\d{0,2}(\.\d{3})*(,\d+)?$/;
pattern.test(input);
```

but it always gave  me false;

I don't want to use `$.isNumeric` as it does not check for commas.

Comment: You mean a comma instead of the dot ? If so it would imply be `/^[1-9]\d{0,2}([\.,]\d{3})*$/`

Comment: Actually I need to check  number 399,090.00  but both commas and dots are optional.

Comment: @user: Are you in a locale where `.` is the thousands separator and `,` is the decimal point? From the regex, you seem to be. E.g., do you write one thousand twenty-three and a half as `1,023.5` or `1.023,5`?

Comment: Did you mean to say `39,900.00`?

Comment: @LShetty: The first digit of the initial triad is specified by the `[1-9]`, so `399,090.00` would work except that the regex appears to be backward re `.` and `,`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your sample var input is not matched by your regex because of the dot.
You could do:

```
var input=3433;
var pattern=/^[1-9]\d{0,2}(\.?\d{3})*(,\d+)?$/;
//    the dot is optional  __^
pattern.test(input);
```

This regex will match:

- `123`
- `1234`
- `1.234`
- `123,45`
- `1234,567`
- `1.234,56`
- `1.234.567,89`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the comma as a thousands separator, the easiest way to do this is to just remove the commas when converting:

```
var num = +str.replace(/,/g, '');
if (!isNaN(num)) {
    // It's a valid number
}
```

If your locale uses `.` as the thousands separator and `,` as a decimal point (as your regex seems to suggest), since JavaScript always uses them the other way around, we have more to change in the string first:

```
var num = +str.replace(/\./g, '').replace(/,/g, ".");
if (!isNaN(num)) {
    // It's a valid number
}
```

Comment: @LShetty: LOL! Indeed. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I must process in different ways strings and string-numbers.
So I must test if a string is a string-number (not a valid number), using the locale convention.

My rude solution is:

```
var num = +str.replace(/\./g, '').replace(/,/g, '');
if (!isNaN(num))...
```

This works with USA, EUR locales. The control about 'valid number' is done after, car I wanna send detailed WARNING/ERROR messages to user.